# SwiftUI: Possible to manage a single struct for a variety of Shape Protocols?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Goal:**
To have a single struct to manage the appearance and behavior of a custom `View`.

**Status:**
I have a simple view model which maintains an array of data representing the view. At run time, I draw these views as follows:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Vstack() {
            ForEach(viewModel.data, id: \.id) { data in 
                switch data.shape {
                    case .circle:
                        MyViewCircle(isHighlighted: data.willHighlight)
                    case .ellipses:
                        MyViewEllipses(isHighlighted: data.willHighlight)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyViewCircle: View {
    var isHighlighted: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            /// a bunch of modifiers
    }
}

struct MyViewEllipses: View {
    var isHighlighted: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Ellipses()
            ///A bunch of modifiers that mirror exactly MyViewCircle
    }
}
```

This works fine and I am able to update my viewModel which will update my views accordingly.

[image: My Shapes drawing, I can even tap on the view and update my view model and highlight the corresponding shapes (code not shown for brevity]

However, in my case, `MyViewCircle` or `MyViewEllipses` will have the exact same appearance and behavior, and the only thing different is it's Shape, also I plan on adding a number of other shapes and even custom drawn shapes.

**What I'd like to do**
I'd like to be able to pass an `enum` or `protocol` or something in my ForEach loop that would draw the shape I want and simplify without the need for a long switch statement. Something like this:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            ForEach(viewModel.data, id: \.id) { data in 
                MyViewProtocol(shape: data.shape, isHighlighted: data.IsHighlighted)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Parent, Super class, protocol, whatever the proper name for `MyViewProtocol` would look something like:

```swift
struct MyViewProtocol: View {
    var shape: ShapeEnum
    var isHighlighted: Bool

    var body: some View {
        switch shape:
        case .circle:
            Circle()
        case .ellipses:
            Ellipses()
        case .triangle:
            MyTrinagle()
        // etc.....
    }
}
```

I have been scouring any/all WWDC talks, YouTube tutorials, medium articles, and the closest thing I could find was on SO here: [Creating BaseView class in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686218/creating-baseview-class-in-swiftui) which is useful for creating a set of modifiers of views, however I'm still in a lurch if I want to be able to use a plethora of shapes managed by one parent struct view.

I may also be having problems because perhaps this is a red flag bad design pattern for a declarative language like SwiftUI!

I would be so grateful for any tips or ideas!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative to switch statement in SwiftUI ViewBuilder block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736466/alternative-to-switch-statement-in-swiftui-viewbuilder-block)

Comment: This is really good thank you @pawello2222

Comment: The AnyShape from [How to use same set of modifiers for various shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62605936/12299030)  can be useful for your case, I think.

Comment: @Asperi this is a REALLY elegant solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can avoid a switch statement, since you need a mapping between your `ShapeEnum` case and the actual view, but you can centralize it in one place:

```
enum ShapeEnum {
   case circle, ellipse, square // etc...
}
```

```
extension ShapeEnum: View {
   var body: AnyView {
      switch self {
      case circle:   return AnyView(Circle())
      case ellipse:  return AnyView(Ellipse())
      // ...
      default:       return AnyView(EmptyView())
      }
   }
}
```

And the usage could be:

```
@State var shapes: [ShapeEnum] = [.circle, .circle, .ellipse]

var body: some View {
   ForEach(shapes, id: \.self) { shape in
      shape
         .padding()
         .background(Color.red)
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh AnyView! This is really helpful and I'll play around with this, thank you New Dev!

Answer (score 1):

While @New Dev and @Pawello2222 had really good sources/solutions, I think the most elegant solution from @Asprei with [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602166/how-to-use-same-set-of-modifiers-for-various-shapes/62605936#62605936) is the winner.