# Create a common layout for the navigation bar in SwiftUI, so other SwiftUI views should reuse same Nav Bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

In iOS SwiftUI, how can we make a common layout for the navigation bar, so we can use that in all projects without rewriting the same code?

[image]

We can use ViewBuilder to create a base view for common code as follows:

```
struct BaseView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    var body: some View {
        // To-do: The most important part will go here
    }
}
```

How can we add navigation bar code in View Builder or base view?

Comment: Did you try to define the navigation bar in a different struct view and use it as an overlay in different views?

Comment: No, i haven't tried that approach. I had tried to add Navigation bar in Base view, but this approach is not working.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an extension of `view` like this way. You can check out [my blog entry for details](https://medium.com/@aayan.talukdar/creating-a-common-navigation-appbar-in-swiftui-7968249b3700).

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    /// CommonAppBar
    public func appBar(title: String, backButtonAction: @escaping() -> Void) -> some View {

        self
            .navigationTitle(title)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                backButtonAction()
            }) {
                Image("ic-back") // set backbutton image here
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .foregroundColor(Colors.AppColors.GrayscaleGray2)
            })
    }
}
```

Now you can use this appBar in any place of the view.

```
struct TransactionsView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {

        }
        .appBar(title: "Atiar Talukdar") {
            self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}

struct TransactionsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TransactionsView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is [being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420925/2370483)

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to use a custom view as an overlay.

For example, consider the below code which makes a custom navigation bar using an overlay:

```
struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            // Your Content
        }
        .overlay {
            ZStack {
                Color.clear
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                    .blur(radius: 10)

                Text("Navigation Bar")
                    .font(.largeTitle.weight(.bold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
            }
            .frame(height: 70)
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        }
    }
}
```

The ZStack inside the `.overlay` will make a view that looks like a navigation bar. You can then move it to its own struct view, add different variables to it and call it from the overlay.

Comment: Thanks @arata for response, Can we write some wrapper on Navigation view So we can take benefit of default Nav Bar functionality in some classes if required.

Comment: @GrayFox So, you want to modify the default navigation bar rather than making a new one from scratch? (This one is also a similar questions in a way) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686218/creating-baseview-class-in-swiftui

Comment: Yes @arata, it would be better if we use existing Navigation bar rather than to create a new one.

Comment: Yes @arata, In that question[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686218/creating-baseview-class-in-swiftui]  View Modifier is used to create a base view, But i wanna to reuse Navigation bar is same manner if possible.

Comment: @GrayFox interesting, never thought of it in that way. Maybe someone could answer your question.